# Automatically adjust ringtone volume Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, automation, volume-control

Some time ago (Android 4.1) I used to use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) app to automatically adjust the ringer volume and dim the screen when my phone connected my work WiFi.
That was a fantastic functionality.

I've just got a Bluboo Picasso 4G (Android 6.0) and want the same.

Llama is not able to change the volume nor brightness anymore. I tried Automate app (newer solution from Llama's author), and it has the ability to choose one of the predefined profiles: *silent*, *vibrate*, *normal*, but it cannot switch to an user-defined profile (only the standard three are available; trying to use variables do not take any effect).

Now I'm testing [PhoneProfilesPlus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.henrichg.phoneprofilesplus) (3.5.0.6) and this seems not to work as well.

Does anyone know a working solution? **All I need is: set some not-very-loud ringtone and dim the screen when connected to my office WiFi, and revert once disconnected.**

Comment: Try out tasker app.

Comment: Standard Android does not support such "profiles", therefor Automate has no block for it. If you're referring to Do-Not-Disturb modes, use the Interruptions set block.

Comment: **Question may be closed**: Actually it seems to be a kind of a bug in my phone. Changing the volume value does not have any effect on the sound. I have tested (QPython+SL4A) that the Android's volume value is changed by the software mentioned in the question, but there is no difference in the sound volume...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still possible with [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) to dim the screen and change the volume.

1. In the Connectivity section, select "Wi-Fi connected". Click on it, enter the Network Name (or click on `Pick network` to select a Network (the WiFi must be on, if not the list will be empty)). Click Done.
2. In the Settings section, select "Screen brightness set". Click on it, enter the Brightness level (expressed in percentage). Click Done.
3. In the Camera & Sound section, select "Audio volume set". Click on it, enter the Volume level (expressed in percentage), then in `Audio Stream`, select `Ring` (`System` is for system-wide sounds). Click Done.
4. Steps 2 and 3 parameters are for when the phone is connected to a selected Wifi network. Repeat steps 2 and 3, but change the parameter to reflect brightness and volume values when the phone is disconnected from the selected Wifi network.
5. Link the blocks as seen on the picture below. Save the flow and give it a name. Give the appropriate permissions (some maybe installed). Click Start.
6. Optional - If you want, the flow to run at boot, in the settings, select `Run on system startup`

[image: IMG:]